# MySql credentials

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to install MySql.

The installer asks for username and password, it says it's provided in the server configuration but I don't know how to get such information.

Any help?

[image]

Comment: do you mean it's asking for you to specify a default username and password for mysql to have once it's installed? Normally it will ask you to set the root password, at least. Or do you mean it's asking you for administrator credentials on the machine itself, so the operating system will allow you to proceed with the install? It's not clear what you mean. Please provide the exact details for what you are being asked, maybe using a screenshot, and specify what operating system you are installing on. We can't really tell precisely what you are asking about.

Comment: P.S. "they say"...who is "they" exactly? We are not mind-readers. Are you referring to some specific piece of documentation? If so can you link to it or quote from it here? That might also help to clarify what you are talking about.

Comment: Sorry.
I added a screenshot to make it easy!

Comment: Thanks. You appear to be installing the sample databases and code examples, rather than the mysql server itself. Therefore, it assumes you already have a MySQL server available - although looking at your screenshot it seems it could not find any instances already running on the machine. Therefore it's asking for the password of an existing MySQL server to which it can install the samples. But as I say, it looks like you don't  have one, or at least not on the same machine. Did you already install MySQL Server before you ran this installer, or not?

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-install-mysql-database-server-8-0-19-on-windows-10/ provides a guide to the full install process, including the option of installing these samples once the server itself it installed

Comment: Try following this link
https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04/

Comment: @AnkitJindal Your suggestion is very strange, and almost certainly not helpful. Did you look at the screenshot? OP is clearly using Windows, not Ubuntu or anything else. Also they never asked for phpMyAdmin, only MySQL. And also I've already provided a link to a relevant tutorial.

Comment: Ohh sorry I mistakenly sent for phpmyadmin. But your issue seems like you have not setup user for the database. Please create a db user and grant permissions to the db user for your database

Comment: Thank you for your help. I greatly appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

You need to manually install mysql server by using the add option in the Mysql intsaller. Add mysql server 8.0 or something.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to enter the password that matches the one you have created during the installation process

Answer (score -2):

don't you have a mysql server ? if yes please add those credentials to that. if not you can install XAMPP into your local PC or connect to hosted mysql server.

Can't imagine your requirement and what are going to do.

Comment: XAMPP is overkill here - OP didn't specify they wanted / needed any of the other tools provided in that package. Simply installing MySQL server alone would be sufficient.